# Merging tables in Power Query on multiple conditions including substrings

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I'm relatively new to Power Query and it's functionality is doing my head in.

I'm trying to join my first well defined table with a second table that has data input as free text (shudder).

What I would like to try and do is the following:

```
left join if table1.id = table2.id OR
    table1.id in table2.metadata OR
    (firstName in metadata AND lastName in metadata)
```

Is there any way of actually doing this? See below for example tables.
One of my problems is that I can't really extract what I need from the metadata into new columns as these values don't have specific delimiters, all values aren't always there, and sometimes the order is not the same.

I have two tables:
**Table 1**

| date | firstName | lastName | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/01/2023 | John | Smith | 123456 |
| 1/01/2023 | Jane | Doe | 654321 |

**Table 2**

| date | metadata | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/02/2023 | some text 1235: John-Smith-something | 123456 |
| 1/02/2023 | some-text: 1236 Jane_Doe_something 654321 | null |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

Add a new column as follows.

```
Table.SelectRows(Table2,
(x)=> [ID]= x[ID] or 
Text.Contains(x[metadata], Text.From( [ID])) or 
(Text.Contains(x[metadata],[firstName]) and Text.Contains(x[metadata],[lastName]))

)
```

[image]

FYI, PQ has quite a powerful fuzzy merge option too which might be useful for non-exact matches.

Comment: Thank you very much, David. I can't believe it was that simple. Unfortunately this place is running on older software, so there a a few Excel and PQ methods I haven't been able to use, fuzzy logic being one of them.